# Image sequence into animation

Tags: modeling, animation, image-sequence

How can I convert image sequence into animation in blender and export it as .blend file?

Comment: In the Video Sequencer in Sequencer mode you can press A > Image/Sequence and it will load a series of images, you'll be able to see it in the Video Sequencer in Preview mode, is it what you want? Except you can't pack the loaded images, you need to keep them in their folder

Comment: Can you please send me any document/video/tutorial for this? I tried to do it but did not succeed.

Comment: Do you have a series of pictures that are named image1.png, image2.png, etc? You need to search for a tutorial like this one I guess: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRsYkp3GoK0